# natural log integral question dx/(13-x)

Tags: integration

Just wondering why the answer to the integral:

$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{13-x}$$

is $-\ln|x-13|$ as opposed to $-\ln|13-x|$. Why do the $13$ and $x$ get switched?

Comment: Those expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|-a| = |a|$ is the fundamental property of absolute value. Now, let $a=x-13$ and note $-a = 13-x$.